# Remove redundant grey vertical lines from plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I plot using ggplot I get grey vertical lines on my plot before data chart. Any ideas on how to remove it would be highly appreciated.

```r
ggplot(fitbit_data, aes(x = Date, y = Steps)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "green") + 
  labs(title = "My Steps", subtitle = " June - Dec 2019", 
       x = " Date", y = "Steps") + 
  scale_x_date(
    date_labels = "%b\n%Y",
    date_breaks = "1 month",
    limits = c(as.Date("2019-06-01"), as.Date("2019-12-31"))
  )
```

[image: bar plot with redundant lines at front]

Comment: Can you add an image of the graph you are currently obtaining in order people can visualize your issue ? Also, can you add a small reproducible example of your data ? (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Fastest way would be adding `+ theme_classic()` or `+ theme_minimum()` to your code. Otherwise modify these `panel.grid, panel.grid.major, panel.grid.minor,
  panel.grid.major.x, panel.grid.major.y, panel.grid.minor.x,
  panel.grid.minor.y` https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html

Comment: Btw I suspect your `Steps` are not numeric. Run `str(fitbit_data)` or `summary(fitbit_data)` to check

Comment: I guess the data imported is somewhere converted to factors (perhaps even when loading the data) which leads to a categorical y-axis, that then appears with overlapping labels that look like those grey columns.

Comment: Thank you all, you are correct.  Didn't realize steps data type got changed during import.  It works now :)

Answer (score 0):

Likely the data is converted to factor, thus ggplot shows a categorical y-axis,  that then appears with overlapping labels that look like those grey columns.

When reading the data make sure to use

```r
df= read.table(..., 
               # assign appropriate data types by using
               colClasses = c(...),
               ... ,
               # it can also be adviseable to use
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```